# package org.apache.cordova does not exist android studio

Tags: android, apache, cordova, android-studio, package

I am using apache cordova to make an application, so I have done all the steps for build in terminal: 'cordova build android', it works perfectly. When I use 'cordova run android', it works again, opens the simulator and I can test the app. But when I want to build it with android studio, for making a signed apk, I have this error:

> package org.apache.cordova does not exist

The error is coming from the folder src/fr.myapp.myapp/MainActivity: `import org.apache.cordova.*;`.

How can I add this package or fix the error?

Note that when I build on ios, I have no error and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have imported only your applications. Not the library projects.

Steps to import Phonegap project :

1. Import Project(Eclipse,ADT etc)
2. Select your project from the directory(Do not select Android directory, select will the whole project, then only all the cordova libs will be imported
   [image]

Check whether you get this dialog(If not, not a prob)[image]

3. **If Yes,** make sure you select all the libraries.[image]

For Step 2, if you didnt get the dialog, click next and open your project. 
In that File-> Import Module to import all the libraries again.

Guess I'm clear

Comment: Thanks guys you saved my life ^^! I love this community <3