# Importing Cordova project to Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, android-studio, android-studio-import

I'm attempting to transfer my project created with cordova over from eclipse to android studio but it's telling me my files are being ignored after import. I've even clicked all of the necessary boxes but am seeing the same result.

[image]

It's not just one but it seems like all of my cordova phonegap files (as seen in the picture below). Does anyone have a suggestion on what is happening?

[image]

Comment: Might help you


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29843646/package-org-apache-cordova-does-not-exist-android-studio/29846383#29846383

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but you can't do it. It's impossible to do...

Why? First of all because of language. As I know (prove if I am wrong) in  `Cordova` you used to work with `Web` technologies, mainly `JavaScript`.

In Android Studio the main language is `Java`, not `JavaScript`. Do not compare these languages - they're a way different. Of course, you can also code in `C++`,`Kotlin`, `RxJava`. For writing tests you can use `Python`, `Groovy` or `Ruby` - but only if you include specific libs in your projects dependencies.

Of course, you need also to notice, that in `Cordova` you code hybrid mobile apps, whereas in `Android Studio` thanks to `Java` native apps.

Another thing is Android Studio build system called `Gradle`, which I suppose you didn't have.

To resume, you cannot do that. If you want to start developing apps in Android Studio, learn `Java`. Of course, in your `Cordova` app you had used some resources like images, fonts. In process of learning programming native apps in `Java` you would re-used them.

If you're looking for good video course for Learning Android development in Java: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLonJJ3BVjZW6hYgvtkaWvwAVvOFB7fkLa

Check also `Coursera` and `Udacity` for more great tuts.

Hope it help and ...good luck!